# Contact form will not send unless is empty

Tags: php, html, forms, contact-form

I just created a contact form and it will only be sent if it is empty the moment there is any text in any input field it just shows the index template on the contact page which is not what I want.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: Web design client'; 
$to = 'placeholder@mail.bcu.ac.uk'; 
$subject = 'Client';

$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
        echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
    }
}

?>

<form class="contact" method="post">
            <div class="slot-6-7">    
                <label>
                    Name
                </label>
                <input class="input" name="name" placeholder="Type Here">   
                <label>
                    Email
                </label>
                <input class="input" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Type Here">
            </div>
            <div class="slot-8-9">
                <label>
                    Message
                    </label>
                <textarea name="message" placeholder="Type Here"></textarea>    
                <input class="submit" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
            </div>
        </form>
```

The e-mail has been change por privacy issues and the site can be seen at http://www.45-records.co.uk/contact/

What I need is to have a contact email sent when someone types their queries down but I can't find the error in the code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$from = 'From: Web design client';` you should be using proper `From:` headers (as in an Email address) and not just text. Most likely ending up in Spam or rejected.

Comment: I just found out that it changes to the index template when there is something written in the Name input, but no on the other two.

Comment: Also use `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` instead of `if ($_POST['submit'])` while making sure your submit button is named. I.e.: `name="submit"` including all other form elements. If they are not named, it will contribute to it and fail. `name="Submit"` and `name="submit"` are not the same, which could be another factor. Show your form.

Comment: Why dont you just check if your 4 variables are `isset`

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: I would recommend using either of the following two mail classes https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer or http://swiftmailer.org/

Comment: @EdCottrell its not the correct format it should be `From: someone@someplace.com`

Comment: `<input class="input" name="name" placeholder="Type Here">` you have no `type` set for it, which could be another "contributing" factor, so try `<input class="input" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Type Here">` I have seen that happen before.

Comment: @cmorrissey, I know I could use one of those, but the idea of the poject is to learn php. Thanks for the heads up though.

Comment: This is what the snippet you game returns: Notice: Undefined index: name in /customers/2/d/9/45-records.co.uk/httpd.www/wp-content/themes/portfolio/contact.php on line 44 Notice: Undefined index: email in /customers/2/d/9/45-records.co.uk/httpd.www/wp-content/themes/portfolio/contact.php on line 45 Notice: Undefined index: message in /customers/2/d/9/45-records.co.uk/httpd.www/wp-content/themes/portfolio/contact.php on line 46  I don't know what it meanss though

Comment: Are you trying to run this on your own machine or a hosted service?

Comment: No, Im running it on a server.

Comment: What has error reporting given you and does your server offer/support `mail()`?

Comment: I just tested your code and there's nothing wrong with it. Contact your hosting company.

Comment: I have received e-mails already, its just when I type anything on the name input it just takes me to the same url with the index template

Answer (score 2):

Need to add an EOL character (`"\n"`) after all header instructions. Each instruction needs to conclude with an EOL character.

From header should include at the least, an email address, along with optional name.

Recommend using `isset()` to check if `$_POST['submit']` is set.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$headers = 'From: Web design client <noreply@yourwebsite.com>' . "\n"; // Add EOL character

$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) { // Check if submit variable is set
    if (mail ('placeholder@mail.bcu.ac.uk', 'Client', $body, $headers)) { 
        echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: I changed my code for yours and it still doesn't work. The problem only occurs when I type something in the name input. When I type anything in it it redirects me to the same URL but with a different template. Thanks so much for your help though.

Comment: You might try adding an action to the `<form>` tag as suggested elsewhere to be sure the form is indeed being handled. `<form class="contact" method="post" action="">`

Comment: action="" won't do anything. It's ok, I'll keep trying different things. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would test for whether submit is set rather than true.

Also, I might be missing something but isn't your form missing action=""

Comment: Without an `action` parameter, the form submits to the same URL (which works in this case since form processing code is at the top of the form file)

Comment: So your telling me I've been wasting my time writing action="" all these years!? lol

Comment: definitely not wasted time, you *do* need it to validate according to HTML spec... and, older browsers aren't smart enough to submit to the same page if action is omitted.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very basic way of checking your form. It should tell you (by setting error messages in vars) which fields are causing an issue.

Also, the from header should be using an email address (see below).

Hope this helps in some way.

```
<?php
$error = '0';
if(isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name'] != '') { $name = $_POST['name']; } else { $error = '1'; $error_message = 'Name Not Entered'; }
if(isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] != '') { $email = $_POST['email']; } else { $error = '1'; $error_message = 'Email Not Entered'; }
if(isset($_POST['message']) && $_POST['message'] != '') { $message = $_POST['message']; } else { $error = '1' $error_message = 'Message Not Entered'; }

if($error == '1') {
    echo $error_message;
} elseif($error == '0') {

    $from = 'From: ' . $_POST['name'] . ' <' . $_POST['email'] . '>'; 
    $to = 'placeholder@mail.bcu.ac.uk'; 
    $subject = 'Client';

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

    $send_message = mail($to, $subject, $body, $from);

    if($send_message) {
        echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
    } else {
        echo '<p>Something Wrong</p>';
        }
}
?>

<form class="contact" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <div class="slot-6-7">    
        <label>
            Name
        </label>
        <input class="input" name="name" placeholder="Type Here">   
        <label>
            Email
        </label>
        <input class="input" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Type Here">
    </div>
    <div class="slot-8-9">
        <label>
            Message
            </label>
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Type Here"></textarea>    
        <input class="submit" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```